# Selenium Element not interactable exception- How to overcome this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on scraping the price of a product from a website using Selenium with Python.
As I run the application,the chromewebdriver opens, as soon as it opens a Notification/message pops up on the website which says to "Accept Cookies", I accept it programmatically however my program stops it execution soon after. The intention is to accept cookies-> Enter the product name(which is done programmatically)->after product is displayed-> The price of product is displayed on my terminal. Here is my code for the same.

```
def scrape_currys(product_name):
    website_address = 'https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/index.html'
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('start-maximized')
    options.add_argument("window-size=1200x600")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

    browser.get(website_address)
    time.sleep(2)

    # browser.implicitly_wait(30)
    browser.find_element_by_id('onetrust-accept-btn-handler').click()
    browser.find_element_by_name('search-field').send_keys(product_name)
    browser.find_elements_by_class_name('Button__StyledButton-bvTPUF hfufmD Button-jyKNMA GZkwS')[0].submit()
    page_source = browser.page_source
    print(page_source)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
    product_price_list = soup.find_all('div', class_='ProductCardstyles__PriceText-gm8lcq-14 lhwdnp')
    return product_price_list[0].text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    product_name_list = ['Canon EF 24-105mm f/4L IS II USM Lens']
    for product in product_name_list:
        scrape_currys(product)
```

The error further reads as `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable` 
Here is the complete stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrapeCurrys.py", line 34, in <module>
    scrape_currys(product)
  File "scrapeCurrys.py", line 22, in scrape_currys
    browser.find_element_by_name('search-field').send_keys(product_name)
  File "/home/mayureshk/PycharmProjects/Selenium-Scraper/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "/home/mayureshk/PycharmProjects/Selenium-Scraper/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/mayureshk/PycharmProjects/Selenium-Scraper/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/mayureshk/PycharmProjects/Selenium-Scraper/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.108)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 5.0.0-1034-oem-osp1 x86_64)
```

I have gone through several answers here regarding the same however none of the attempts have so long been successfull. I have tried everything. I am hopeful to get an answer on this since most of the folks here are really knowledgeable. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me explain what you are doing wrong. The first problem is in the line `browser.find_element_by_name('search-field').send_keys(product_name)`. If you check the html code, you will see that there are two inputs with name 'search-field', the first one is hidden, that is why you were getting the `ElementNotInteractableException`:

[image: input_name]

you can solve it easily by getting all elements and selecting the second one, just change to `browser.find_elements_by_name('search-field')[1].send_keys(product_name)`

When you made this fix, you will find a similar problem when trying to submit the search using the button. You can use `browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]')[1].click()`

To get the prices, you don't need to use the BeautifulSoup, as you already have all the information you need in your browser object. Just get them with `product_price_list = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//strong[@class="price"]')`

Here is a complete solution example:

```
def scrape_currys(product_name):
    website_address = 'https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/index.html'
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('start-maximized')
    options.add_argument("window-size=1200x600")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

    browser.get(website_address)
    time.sleep(2)

    # browser.implicitly_wait(30)
    browser.find_element_by_id('onetrust-accept-btn-handler').click()
    browser.find_elements_by_name('search-field')[1].send_keys(product_name)
    browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]')[1].click()
    
    product_price_list = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//strong[@class="price"]')
    return [elem.text for elem in product_price_list]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    product_name_list = ['Canon EF 24-105mm f/4L IS II USM Lens']
    for product in product_name_list:
        price_list = scrape_currys(product)
        print(price_list_list)
```

output:

```
['£2,329.00', '£409.00', '£1,629.00', '£1,249.00', '£1,149.00', '£649.00', '£959.00', '£599.00', '£329.00', '£589.00', '£2,049.00', '£419.00', '£1,349.00', '£669.00', '£639.00']
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to try other element locators when you get an error related to finding the element. This will work:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def scrape_currys(product_name):
    website_address = 'https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/index.html'
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('start-maximized')
    options.add_argument("window-size=1200x600")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

    browser.get(website_address)
    time.sleep(2)

    # browser.implicitly_wait(30)
    browser.find_element_by_id('onetrust-accept-btn-handler').click()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header"]/div[1]/form/div/div/input').send_keys(product_name + Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(2)
    page_source = browser.page_source
    print(page_source)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
    product_price_list = soup.find_all('div', class_='ProductCardstyles__PriceText-gm8lcq-14 lhwdnp')
    return product_price_list[0].text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    product_name_list = ['Canon EF 24-105mm f/4L IS II USM Lens']
    for product in product_name_list:
        scrape_currys(product)
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your quick response. I understood where you made some changes,The script works fine however that prints a lot of unwanted stuff as well. I only wanted to print the prices of the products and not everthing- It does even print the html codes.